# React Native Filter Query

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, linq

I have following data. For example I want to select all data if data.groupId includes 2 in JavaScript. How Can I do this.

```
data= [
{
    id: 13,
    name: 'Pilav3',
    orderNumber: 5,
    groupId: [121, 11, 1]
 },
{
    id: 14,
    name: 'Pilav4',
    orderNumber: 6,
    groupId: [121, 12, 2]
 },
{
    id: 15,
    name: 'Pilav5',
    orderNumber: 7,
    groupId: [121, 11, 1]
 },
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
data.filter(d=>return d.groupid.includes(2))
```